# JS Time Tracker not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a timer mainly using javascript, currently the start/stop functionality works fine.  When user hits "Stop" button it takes the time from the #time element, converts it to decimal value and updates the hidden #counter element.  For example an 1 and a half hours would be converted to 1.50

My problem is I also want to allow users to edit the time manually so I have a little plugin that was created to do allow for this.

**There are 2 problems:**

1. If a user manually adds their time by double clicking the element and adjusting then were to hit save, the #counter element has not be updated so it is submitting the time as 0.
2. If a user were to manually set their time and then hit the Start button, the clock starts from 0 instead of the time they specified.

I have a JS Fiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/pkj7wyLu/

Toward the bottom of the JS block in that fiddle you will see:

```
//implement plugin
        $('span#time').editable().on('editsubmit', function (event, val) {
            console.log('text changed to ' + millisecondsToHours(val));
        });
```

which I believe is the event that fires each time the user manually enters time.

**Question:** How can I make it where when someone manually enters time that it automatically updates the #counter field with the converted values and if they press start it starts from that time?

**What I tried:** I tried playing with the `format(Time)` function and have it currently trying to print the value to the console but I am not getting results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an override method on your `clsStopwatch` class, like so:

```
this.override = function(time) {
        lapTime = time;
}
```

This will update the `lapTime`, passing in a time in milliseconds. To do this I created a new function which accepts a string:

```
function stringToMilliseconds(str) {
        var a = str.split(':'); // split it at the colons
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 
        return seconds * 1000;
}
```

This will return the number of milliseconds from the edited string in the id `#time` element span.

Finally, I updated the submit editable event to call the override:

```
$('span#time').editable().on('editsubmit', function (event, val) {
        x.override(stringToMilliseconds(val));
});
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk7ztbh8/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Derek No problem, let me know if you need anything else. Matt